# packer: error when provisioning with vmware-vmx

Tags: vmware, packer

I am building an `.ova` file using as source a base image (which is in `.vmx` format).

The base image (created as said above in `.vmx` format) is built from an `Ubuntu 16.04` server using `vmware-iso` builder.

Here is my `builder` configuration

```
"builders": [
       {
        "type": "vmware-vmx",
        "vmx_data": {
          "memsize": "8192",
          "numvcpus": "4"
       },
       "source_path": "path/to/base.vmx",
```

The first provisioner that will run is the following:

```
 "provisioners": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": [
          "sudo apt-get update -y",
          "sudo apt-get upgrade -y",

...
```

However, although I have repeated the process many times, it suddenly breaks with the following error:

```
==> vmware-vmx: Cloning source VM...
==> vmware-vmx: Starting HTTP server on port 8031
==> vmware-vmx: Starting virtual machine...
==> vmware-vmx: Waiting 10s for boot...
==> vmware-vmx: Connecting to VM via VNC (127.0.0.1:5924)
==> vmware-vmx: Typing the boot command over VNC...
==> vmware-vmx: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> vmware-vmx: Connected to SSH!
==> vmware-vmx: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell747369685
    vmware-vmx: Reading package lists...
    vmware-vmx: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    vmware-vmx: E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
==> vmware-vmx: Stopping virtual machine...
==> vmware-vmx: Deleting output directory...
Build 'vmware-vmx' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

> The lock is placed when an apt process is running, and is removed when the process completes.  If there is a lock with no apparent process running, this may mean the process got stuck for some reason.